# Modified User Input value in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a requirement to read the string passed by the user and later modify the string to get a required format and pass it as a where condition to the view.

Example
the user inputs a list of material numbers separated by commas '12345,78990,456789'.  this string has to be modified to

MATCH("BOM_PATH",'*12345*') OR MATCH("BOM_PATH",'*78990*') OR MATCH("BOM_PATH",'*456789*')

So basically I need to separate all materials from the input string and search for those individual materials in a field called BOM_PATH which holds the value like '12345:098765:784526'

I tried using Snowflake SQL UDTF but it doesn't support variables or multiple SQL statements and Snowflake view doesn't support parameters.

So please suggest me a way on how to implement this in Snowflake.

Comment: I would need to understand your input and suggested code to fully understand your question here...do you mind elaborating?  It sounds like something a UDTF would work great for.  Maybe a JS UDTF would work?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using [ARRAY_CONTAINS()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_contains.html) function with the input converted to the array by [STRTOK_TO_ARRAY()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/strtok_to_array.html).

```
create or replace table bom_table(BOM_PATH varchar);
insert into bom_table (BOM_PATH)
values
('12345'),
('55555'),
('77778'),
('78990');

select * from bom_table 
where 
ARRAY_CONTAINS(BOM_PATH::variant,STRTOK_TO_ARRAY('12345,78990,456789',','));
```

Alternatively, if your BAM_PACH is a delimited list too - use [ARRAY_INTERSECTION()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_intersection.html) and [ARRAYS_OVERLAP()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/arrays_overlap.html)

```
insert into bom_table (BOM_PATH)
values
('12345:098765:784526'),
('12346:098766:784527'),
('12345:098765:777777'),
('12399:098765:777773');

select ARRAY_INTERSECTION(STRTOK_TO_ARRAY(BOM_PATH,':'),STRTOK_TO_ARRAY('12345,78990,456789',',')) from bom_table 
where ARRAYS_OVERLAP(STRTOK_TO_ARRAY(BOM_PATH,':'),STRTOK_TO_ARRAY('12345,78990,456789',','));
```